# angularjs $http.post error Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a WCF Service hosted inside a SharePoint site with angularjs $http.post

The signature of the wCFService is as follows

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CheckAnother", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
void PostAlertConfigss(string name);
```

The corresponding javascript call is

```
return $http.post('/_vti_bin/NSPAlert/NSPAlert.svc/CheckAnother', { 'name': alertItemsCollection })
```

I get the following error,

**"Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode"**

Does anyone know how to fix this?